# using office scripts to read superScripts characters from a cell in excel online

Tags: excel, typescript, ms-office, number-formatting, office-scripts

I am trying to read content from excel using office scripts , cells of this excel contain multiple numbers , some of those are formatted as superscripts. when I try to read data from these cells with office scripts ( Typescript) it returns the content of cell  as normal numbers ( completely ignoring the superscripts , displaying them as usual numbers ).
Another issue , is that once I select the content of the cell in excel online , the cell loses its superscript formatting ,and I get it back only using ( CTRL + Z) .

I tried to fill in a new cell in the same excel file , but this time with data containing superscripts that I created and copied from this site [SuperScriptGenerator](https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator) : Now I can select the content of the cell without losing the formatting of the superscript characters , I can also read the content of the cell with office scripts , and that would display the content of the cell while preserving the superscript characters.

Am aware that this could be a text encoding issue , but in this case , on excel online , I couldn't identify the encoding of the text ? neither why the  string I copied from the superscript generator and pasted on the excel worked fine , while the already existing superscripts are causing issues ( superscripts formatting disappears once I select the cell content, and appearing as usual numbers when reading the cell content with officeScripts/typescript) ! Any help or hints on this case. Thank you

Comment: Would you be able to share a few examples of the data you are trying to read with Office Scripts? As far as I can tell, superscript formatting isn't available in Excel online. Rendering of formats applied elsewhere should work. I'd like to try a few tests with data that is like yours.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that by default superscript/subscript texts in Office Apps (Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.) are actually just regular characters rendered with special formatting properties. I think a good analog of this is probably the [`<sup>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) and [`<sub>`](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_sub.asp) tags in HTML.

For example, in HTML, `A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> = C<sup>2</sup>` will be rendered as:

> A<sup>2</sup> + B<sup>2</sup> = C<sup>2</sup>

But if you copy it and paste into a plain text editor like Notepad, you will notice it will become:

> A2 + B2 = C2

This is because any formatting properties (in this case, the `<sup>` property) would get lost for plain text.

The Office Scripts APIs `getValue` and `getText` has the same behavior since currently they only support plain texts/numbers without any formatting properties.

But then you would ask - why can the text copied from SuperScriptGenerator retain their superscript formatting?

The answer is "**Unicode Symbols**"!

Now you can try to copy this text and paste into Notepad again:

> A² ⁺ B² ⁼ C²

You'll notice the superscripts still look correct in Notepad this time!

This is because there are no special superscript formatting properties involved here. The small number `²` is just a special Unicode Symbol that can be retained with any plain text that supports Unicode.

So apparently SuperScriptGenerator uses those Unicode Symbols to represent superscripts, which won't get lost in translation.

BTW, the selecting behavior in Excel Online does sound to me like a bug (or at least a limitation). It seems like it will automatically format all the characters in the cell with the formatting properties of the first character. So if you have something like "**<sup>2</sup>A**" in a cell, you select it in edit mode and move out you will end up with "**<sup>2A</sup>**".